# Почему не работает параметр "margin-top"?

Tags: html, css

Параметр у `#slider`: http://jsfiddle.net/NPBrq/2/

```css
    #header {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #header-holder {
        background-color: #ccc;
        margin: 35px auto 20px auto;
        width: 950px;
    }
    #slider {
        background-color: red;
        clear: both;
        height: 335px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #slider-holder {
        margin: 0px auto;
        width: 950px;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <body>
        
        <div id="header">
            <div id="header-holder">
               <div id="logo"></div>
               <div id="menu"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="slider">
            <div id="slider-holder">
               LOREM
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: У меня работает (Linux - Opera)

Comment: ссылку не ту дал. сорри. исправил

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Почитайте про [CSS коллапс](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing).

Плюс, вам поможет такая фенька:

```
#header-holder{
    width:950px;
    margin: 35px auto 20px auto;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    overflow: hidden;/*Фенька*/
}
```

Отвечая на вопрос прямо:
Хидер у вас схлопывается. Просто потому что он "не чувствует" флоатовых элементов внутри.
Подтверждение - отсутствие серого фона хидера(#ccc) в вашем примере.
Костыль для решения - сделать overflow-hidden. Тогда он автоматически надуется, если не указывать высоту.

Из-за схлопывания хидера, элемент, у которого clear:both, "думает", что он и так достаточно далеко от хидера, чтобы включать маргин. Этот эффект называется коллапс отступов(попробуйте поставить вертикально два элемента с разными маргинами. Победит тот, у кого маргин больше, меньший просто схлопнется в него.)

```
#div1{
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#div2{
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

будет выглядеть так, будто между ними только 20 px.

Comment: прочитаю на досуге, а можно сейчас в 2 словах, чтобы не сидеть долго на месте?

Comment: можно. Но отнюдь не в двух. =(( Это сложная и глючная штука.

Comment: спасибо за полный ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Поставил `float:left` и все заработало:

```
#slider{
   width:100%;
   margin-top:20px;
   clear:both;
   float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощенья, но почему не дали самый простой ответ: сбросить обтекние сразу после того как закончились обтекаемые блоки?
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPBrq/5/)

Добавляем в CSS:

```
.clearer {
   clear: both;  
}
```

И сразу после лого и меню:

```
<div id="header-holder">
   <div id="logo"></div>
   <div id="menu"></div>
   <br class="clearer">
</div>
```

Вообщем-то все :)

Если вам не навится дополнительный тег, которому действительно там не место, то обратите внимание на такую штуку - **clearfix**.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPBrq/6/)

Вместо **clearer** прорабатываем этот **clearfix**:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: "\0020"; 
    display: block; 
    height: 0; 
    clear: both; 
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.clearfix {
    display: block;
}

.clearfix {
    //display: inline-block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

И тогда ваш HTML останется таким, каким вы его хотели изначально:

```
<div id="header-holder" class="clearfix">
   <div id="logo"></div>
   <div id="menu"></div>
</div>
```